# Focus state styling of UIButtons ignored when using UIButton.Configuration on tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton, tvos

When using `UIButton.Configuration` to style `UIButton`s depending on their state, everything works as expected on iOS.

However, on tvOS the button configuration's `baseBackgroundColor`, `baseForegroundColor`, and `background` properties are ignored in favor of a white background with black text.

This is independent of the configuration used, so it doesn't matter, if it is a `.plain()` or a `.filled()` configuration, for example.

Here comes a sample `UIViewController` with two buttons (one plain, one filled).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private var stackView: UIStackView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let button1 = UIButton(configuration: .plain())
    button1.configuration?.buttonSize = .large
    button1.configuration?.title = "Hello, Button 1!"

    button1.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
        button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = button.state == .focused ? .green : .purple
        button.configuration?.background.backgroundColor = button.state == .focused ? .green : .purple
    }

    let button2 = UIButton(configuration: .filled())
    button2.configuration?.buttonSize = .large
    button2.configuration?.title = "Hello, Button 2!"

    button2.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
        button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = button.state == .focused ? .green : .purple
        button.configuration?.background.backgroundColor = button.state == .focused ? .green : .purple
    }

    stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1, button2])
    stackView?.axis = .vertical
    stackView?.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackView?.spacing = 20
    stackView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let stackView = stackView {
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        let constraints = [
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

}

To see the focused styling on iOS, the code can be run on an iPad simulator with *Full Keyboard Access* enabled. The buttons will be green when focused.

When running on tvOS, the configuration is ignored, though.

Did you happen to stumble upon this problem, and found a solution for this?

Comment: As I expect a different behavior, and believe the current behavior to be a bug, or to be 'wrong' by design, I opened a radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5491185627955200
However, if somebody happens to find a workaround (or finds that I did something wrong), I'd be happy to get some feedback.

Comment: Also appears to be the case with selected state. Both selected and focused states have a white _UIFloatingContentCornerRadiusAnimatingView

Comment: Any updates from apple? I see the radar hasn't been touched. Definitely feels like a bug to me.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately no update from Apple. The ticket is still open, and seemingly untouched.